# JQuery navigating through a TABLE

Tags: jquery

If you have a simple table, followed by a button; how do you from the button then navigate through the rows to evaluate the content...

```
<table id=mydata">
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>somevalue</td>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>somevalue</td>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>somevalue</td>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>somevalue</td>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btnTest">

<script>
  var stringData = "";
  $("#btnTest").click(function(){
    $("#mydata tr").each(function(){
      //if the checkbox is ticked
      stringData += "???" // =>> the 'somevalue' from the same tr
    });
    alert(stringData);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
  var stringData = '';
  $("#btnTest").click(function(){
    $("#mydata :checkbox:checked").each(function(){
         stringData += $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text();
    });
    alert(stringData);
  });
```

alternatively you can change to this if you need to access the index of checked checkboxes tr:

```
stringData += "tr"+ $(this).closest('tr').index() + ":" 
                  + $(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text()
```

Comment: i like answers which not only solve the problem but also teach something to me.

Comment: @northkildonan glad this helped you in someway.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
stringData = "";

$("#btnTest").click(function(){
    $("#mydata tr").each(function(){
      if($(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").is("checked")){
          stringData += $(this).find("td").text();

      }
    });
    alert(stringData);
 });
```